# Is it possible to have a parent process GTK application "contain" child process GTK windows?

Tags: c, multiprocessing, gtk3, inter-process-communicat

I have a simple console application that creates 3 child processes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>


STARTUPINFO si[5];
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi[5];
int procIndex = 0;
void monitor_new_process();
void monitor_shutdown();

/**
 *
 * @see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx
 */
void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) {
    monitor_new_process();
    monitor_new_process();
    monitor_new_process();
    monitor_shutdown();
}

void monitor_new_process() {
    ZeroMemory(&si[procIndex], sizeof(si[procIndex]));
    si[procIndex].cb = sizeof(si[procIndex]);
    ZeroMemory(&pi[procIndex], sizeof(pi[procIndex]));

    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        "consumer",        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si[procIndex],            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi[procIndex])           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    procIndex++;
}

void monitor_shutdown() {
    while (procIndex >= 0){
        // Wait until child process exits.
        WaitForSingleObject(pi[procIndex].hProcess, INFINITE);

        // Close process and thread handles. 
        CloseHandle(pi[procIndex].hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi[procIndex].hThread);
        procIndex--;
    }
}
```

I have also been playing around with GTK+. I've made a simple application that generates a window from a ui file:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkBuilder *builder;
GObject *window;
GObject *button;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    /* Construct a GtkBuilder instance and load our UI description */
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "builder.ui", NULL);

    /* Connect signal handlers to the constructed widgets. */
    window = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window");
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a GTK+ element that I could put into the builder.ui file that could act as a "container" for child processes.

For example, I could have something like this in the builder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Test</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <property name="default_width">440</property>
    <property name="default_height">250</property>
    <property name="destroy_with_parent">True</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkVBox" id="vbox1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="menubar1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem1">              
              <!- ... ->
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <!-- SOME KIND OF CHILD PROCESS CONTAINER -->
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Where `<!-- SOME KIND OF CHILD PROCESS CONTAINER -->` would be an object with an ID, where I could nest a GTK+ window from a child process.

A similar concept is like an iFrame in HTML -- where you can use HTML to designate a frame where an external web application will be nested into a parent container.

Another similar concept is Google Chrome. Chrome's shell is a process, and each tab is a child process. This is essentially exactly what I'm trying to mimic.

What would I need to do in GTK+ and with my child process script to do this? Is this even possible with GTK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Check out [`GtkSocket`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSocket.html) and [`GtkPlug`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkPlug.html). They are only available for the X11 backend of GTK, though, so your application won't be cross-platform: specifically, Windows and native OSX won't support this, and neither will Wayland.